# How to resolve Multiple repeating alarm triggers at the same time

Tags: android, android-alarms

I tried to create an alarm  which will trigger on button click and will repeat on 6:00 am in the morning. The first one that i made worked and is working properly but when i added another repeating alarm it triggers the previous alarm at the same time. So my question is how can I make a multi-alarm work properly?

The code for Repeating alarm

```
 public void setAlarmRepeating()
    {
        AlarmManager dog=(AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent alarm_dog=new Intent(this,Dog_alarm.class);
        PendingIntent pi1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 100,alarm_dog, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 6);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
        dog.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi1);


        AlarmManager dog1=(AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent alarm_dog1=new Intent(this,Dog_alarm.class);
        PendingIntent pi2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 200,alarm_dog1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 7);
        calendar1.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
        calendar1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
        dog1.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar1.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi2);

    }
```

And this is for BroadcastReciever

```
 public class MorningAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        NotificationManager notificationManager1=(NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent dog_intent1=new Intent(context,HomeActivity.class);
        dog_intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent dog_pending1=PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 100,dog_intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder1=new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentIntent(dog_pending1)
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .setContentTitle("Pet Guide 101")
                .setContentText("Time to feed your dog")
                .setAutoCancel(true);
        notificationManager1.notify(100,builder1.build());



        NotificationManager notificationManager2=(NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent dog_intent2=new Intent(context,HomeActivity.class);
        dog_intent2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent dog_pending2=PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 200,dog_intent2, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder2=new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentIntent(dog_pending2)
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                .setContentTitle("Pet Guide 101")
                .setContentText("Time to walk your dog")
                .setAutoCancel(true);
        notificationManager2.notify(200,builder2.build());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you using `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` as flag the current `PendingIntent` update to new extras and no new `PendingIntent` created.

You must create new `PendingIntent` for each alarm.

Use:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
```

Remember for canceling alarms you must restart your device or uninstall your app

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because your alarm manager is not taking your task as time critical

you need to use `setInexactRepeating()` instead of `setRepeating()` function.

hope it will work.